# elasticsearch wild card query not working

Tags: elasticsearch, search, match, wildcard

I seem to be running into a peculiar issue when I run my query with the match directive as below I get a hit

```
{
  "query":
        {"match": {
            "value.account.names.lastName" : "*GUILLERMO*"
          }
    }
}
```

Now when I use the query with the wild card character such as below I don't get a hit.

```
{
  "query":
        {"wildcard": {
            "value.account.names.lastName" : "*GUILLERMO*"
          }
    }
}
```

I am really lost as to what the issue maybe.  Many thanks in advance for any input

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you are trying to run wildcard query against analyzed field the behavior of Elasticsearch is totally correct. As Elasticsearch documentation states wildcard query operates on the terms level. When you index document with field `name` that contains string "Guillermo del Toro" value of that field will be lowercased and split into three tokens: "guillermo", "del" and "toro". Then when you run wildcard query `*GUILLERMO*` against `name` field Elasticsearch compares query string as it is with every single token trying to find a match. Here you will not get a hit just because of your query string is in uppercase and analyzed token is in lowercase.

Running wildcard queries against analyzed field is probably a bad idea but if it is strongly required I would recommend to use built-in `name.keyword` field instead of just `name` field (but again you will face a problem of case sensitivity). Better solution is to create your own lowercased not-analyzed field for that purpose.

Comment: thank you very much for your reply.  So i just ran the wildcard query with lower case and got a hit.  So I guess from what you are saying is that I should always have my partial query term set to lower case to get a match , is this accurate?

Comment: @bobdabelina It depends on the field type. It won't work for analyzed (text) fields when your query string contains more than one term. For example if you will try to run wildcard query `*guillermo ?tor*` you won't get any hit because as I mentioned in my answer Elasticsearch does not apply any transformation to query string leaving it as it is. Obviously the index does not contain any term matching the template `*guillermo ?tor*`. On the other hand built-in `keyword` field contains field value in its original form. But here we face the problem of case sensitivity.

Comment: @bobdabelina As I suggested it is better to create additional `not-analyzed` field containing value in lowercase and then run wildcard queries (that obviously should also be in lowercase) against this field.

Comment: Thank you again for the response. Unfortunately we don't have control over that index and how the fields are created so I am looking for the least invasive way to get the results we want and using lower case seems to be that